# Can we point Azure HDInsight HBASE (HDI 4.0) to a different Data Lake V2 container then the default one

Tags: hbase, azure-hdinsight

Is it possible to point Azure HDInsight HBASE (HDI 4.0) to a container on Data Lake V2 other than the default cluster container to store only HBASE data, 
as one of our customer wants their data to be permanently stored on a container and each time they create a new HBASE cluster they point HBASE to it?

Answer (score 0):

One can specify the container name during cluster creation and re-use the same container again during next cluster creation. CX has to make sure that the container is not being used by more than one Cluster.

https://hdinsight.github.io/ClusterCRUD/ADLS/adls-create-reuse-container.html

Comment: Thanks! I am aware this can be done, but my question is can we use another container other then default to store only HBASE data like the HBASE folder inside our default container resided in another container may be same storage account?

Comment: We are using Data Lake Gen 2.